# How to solve this problem involving convolution of negative input to delta function

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

How to solve this problem involving convolution of negative input to delta function
$$ x(-t) \ast \delta(-t-t_0) $$
$\ast$ - stands for convolution and
$\delta$ stand for - dirac - delta function

Answer (score 0):

$$
x(-t) \ast \delta(-t-t_0)
= x(-t) \ast \delta(t+t_0)
= x(-t) \ast \delta(t-(-t_0)) \\
= x(-(t-(-t_0)))
= x(-(t+t_0)).
$$

First equality: $\delta$ is even.
Second equality: small rewrite.
Third equality: $f(t) \ast \delta(t-t_0) = f(t-t_0)$.
Fourth equality: obvious rewrite.

Comment: Isn't $ f(t) \ast \delta (t-t_0) = f(t-t_0)$ instead of $f(t_0) $  ?

Comment: You're right. I have corrected my calculation.